# Anychart drawing multiple labels on button click

Tags: anychart

This question is a continuation of the question in [Anychart drawing and annotations with React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69010135/anychart-drawing-and-annotations-with-react)

I added a button to add another label in the playground: https://playground.anychart.com/SLAXjcKD/0
But you see that after adding another label, selecting one label and type text change both label text. I tried to use chart.listen('annotationUnselect' to remove listener on the textarea, but still selecting one label and type text change both label text. Any ways to prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to change the text content of certain annotations without affecting other annotations.

To prevent the issue of affecting multiple labels by changing the text in the certain one, you need to remove the previous event listener before adding a new one. Currently, **removeEventListener** does not work [as it is supposed to](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener), which leads to adding up event listeners and never removing them.

Please, change the following lines to make it work

```
var listenFunction = function() {
  selectedAnno.text(textArea.value.trim());
};

textArea.addEventListener('input', listenFunction);

chart.listen('annotationUnselect', function() {
  textArea.removeEventListener('input', listenFunction);
  selectedAnno = null;
});
```

Please, explore the [annotation text changing demo](https://playground.anychart.com/m2VtbMYA) that we’ve prepared.